# October CMS and thousands pages

Tags: octobercms

Can this cms handle and work with thousands of pages? Or do I need to look for another cms to use a plugin to save in db?
Will there be a lot of load on the server with so many pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

October CMS's performance shouldn't really have anything to do with the number of pages, but rather the total traffic. It's possible that having larger numbers of pages would slow things down very marginally by making database SELECTs take longer, but you would probably have to have tens of millions of pages for that to start having an effect, and would be related to the database, not the CMS.

Performance WILL be impacted by the actual traffic (busy-ness) of the website. The developers have already done some benchmarking on this point: https://kinsta.com/blog/php-7-hhvm-benchmarks/#octobercms-benchmarks.

Still, if you need at some point to scale beyond the inherent limitations of the CMS's performance, you can always scale up almost limitlessly by using a caching layer in front of it, load balancing between separate servers, or any of the other techniques used to create high-availability websites. These methods are especially easy and help for sites that are very read-heavy. There are even commercial services like CloudFlare that will do most of this heavy lifting for you.

Comment: well, i have 10k pages and traffic ~5-8k visitors daily, is this ok?

Comment: It would depend how "bursty" it is. If those 5k-8k visitors all come at the same second, you will probably need to beef it up in some way like using a caching layer in front of it.

If they're spread out totally evenly, that means less than one per second, and you should be fine. As long as you're under about 50/second, according to the benchmarks, you should also be fine. That would correspond to about 4.3 million pageviews per day.

In other words, unless your site has a really crazy usage pattern, you should be fine.